# Copying a file remotely from Ubuntu to Windows 7

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-7, command-line, ubuntu-11.10

I am not very familiar with command line Ubuntu (leave alone copying a file remotely) so I apologise if this question is a bit too common.

My setup is a bit unusual so I wasn't able to find much via research online.

I am working on a Win7 machine and I ssh into the Ubuntu (11.10) server via Putty. I tried the following command,

```
scp textFile.txt user@ipaddress:
```

The `textFile.txt` is on the Ubuntu machine and the `user` is my account on the Win7 machine and `ipaddress` is the IPv4 address of the Win machine. I even put the `-4` option but everytime it keeps saying `Connection timed out`.

Is there any way for me to copy this file onto my machine?

Both are on the same network.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest that you get an application called WinSCP installed on your Windows server.  This is free and very easy to use.

It is like an FTP application, using your Linux username and password (along with the SSH port).  This way, all future copies between these OS'es will be easy.

I hope this help?

Comment: Worked to do it te other way as well, from Windows to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You could install samba or FTP to share files.

Using a samba share on the windows machine you could follow [this guide](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/index.php/2007/11/12/accessing-an-smb-remote-folder-from-ubuntu-s-command-line/)

Using FTP you could try [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-vsftpd-ftp-service-server/)

Comment: I like these options as well but I am a bit biased towards a GUI based method of sharing files. Although this is nice to know for some quick copies especially where I may not have WinSCP installed. Thank you!

Comment: I thought you only used ssh so I wrote a CLI solution. I'm pretty sure there's a GUI way of doing the samba (and maybe the ftp way) on ubuntu.

Comment: my only access to the machine yes is ssh, the WinSCP doesnt show me the remote desktop but it just gives a windows explorer kind of look to all the directories and files.

Answer (score 1):

You may use filezilla. I also encountered the same problem however I found Filezilla as one of the easiest way to transfer the file. Check the image and enter the host id sftp://ipaddress.. Oops i realised that I cannot post an image until i have 10 reputation... :( hence, removing the image. but its easy. Just put the host name as suggested above.

hope this will help