# how to transfer and execute a exe file on remote windows machine from ubuntu commandline?

Tags: windows, bash, remote-access, rdp

I have an exe file, that install something on my remote windows machine.

I have some bash script to that should transfer this file to remote windows machine and execute that exe file on that remote windows machine.

This bash script is triggered via some automated pipeline, jenkins.

Can someone help me with the process to achieve this?

What have i tried:

I am totally new to windows remote access. I have done one with RDP and have tried winexe (https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Winexe#Installation_of_winexe), but that is failing to install with error :

`make basics ~/bin/winexe
Creating heimdal/lib/asn1/der-protos.h
syntax error at heimdal/cf/make-proto.pl line 15, near "do Getopts("
Execution of heimdal/cf/make-proto.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
data.mk:195: recipe for target 'heimdal/lib/asn1/der-protos.h' failed
make: *** [heimdal/lib/asn1/der-protos.h] Error 255`

Comment: What part of the process do you need help with? What have you tried?

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: The error you see is really about building winexe, not about the process you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Access to the remote Windows machine, you could install a SFTP/SSH server there, see [this](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server) e.g.

With that, you should be able to:

1. Secure copy the file from you Ubuntu command line

   ```
   scp <your_file> user@ip_win_server:<target location>
   ```
2. Either

   1. Send a command to the Windows server via ssh

      ```
      ssh user@ip_win_server "your command"
      ```
   2. Use Winexe.

Useful refs:

https://zaiste.net/posts/a_few_ways_to_execute_commands_remotely_using_ssh/

[How to execute a remote command over ssh with arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502945/how-to-execute-a-remote-command-over-ssh-with-arguments)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171331/how-to-execute-windows-commands-remotely-from-linux-machine-using-rdesktop-comma

[How to activate programs on windows from Linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633077/how-to-activate-programs-on-windows-from-linux-machine)

[Copying a file remotely from Ubuntu to Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316539/copying-a-file-remotely-from-ubuntu-to-windows-7)

(an old one) https://serverfault.com/questions/10468/ssh-scp-server-on-windows